# How to evaluate $\log x$ to high precision "by hand"

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, approximation

I want to prove

$$\log 2<\frac{253}{365}.$$

This evaluates to $0.693147\ldots<0.693151\ldots$, so it checks out. (The source of this otherwise obscure numerical problem is in the verification of the [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).) If you had to do the calculation by hand, what method or series would you use to minimize the number of operations and/or size of the arguments involved in order to get this result? I'm doing a formal computer proof, so it's not exactly by hand, but I still want to minimize the number of evaluations needed to get to this result.

One method is by rewriting it into $2<e^{253/365}$ and using the power series; since it is a positive series you know you can stop once you have exceeded $2$. Working this out, it seems you need the terms $n=0,\dots,7$ of the sum, and then it works out to

$$2<\sum_{n=0}^7\frac{(253/365)^n}{n!}=\frac{724987549742673918011}{362492763907870312500},$$

which involves rather larger numbers than I'd like. There is also the limit $(1+\frac{253}{365n})^n\to$ $e^{253/365}$, but the convergence on this is not so good; it doesn't get past $2$ until $n=68551$, at which point we are talking about numbers with $507162$ digits.

For $\log 2$ there is of course the terribly converging alternate series $\log 2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{-(-1)^n}n$, which requires $71339$ terms to get the desired bound. This can be improved by pushing the series into its geometrically convergent region as $\log 2=2\log{\sqrt 2}=-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1-\sqrt2)^n}n$, but now there is the added complication of estimating $\sqrt 2$ to sufficient precision. Assuming that $\sqrt 2$ is known exactly, you need to take this series out to $12$ terms, at which point we are verifying

$$\frac{1959675656 \sqrt2-2771399891}{1011780}<0\Leftarrow2771399891^2>1959675656^2\cdot 2.$$

What other methods are there to do a calculation like this? Is there a way to use a root-finding method like Newton's to get a strict bound out with fast convergence?

Comment: One Newton-like method is Newton's method.

Comment: @GFauxPas Yes, but Newton's method as is only gives a convergent series - can you put bounds on the distance to the root?

Comment: The book _Euler: Master of Us All_ has a section on logs that I think might be relevant. (There's an online free version, I think.)

Comment: Also, whenever I do anything involving $e$ or $\ln$, I like to try to do it without any calculus, using only the formula $e^x\ge x+1$. (It's quite effective; it lets you prove that $\ln2=1-\frac12+\frac13-\dotsb$, for example.)

Comment: A practical method to get the fraction $\dfrac {253}{365}$ is to start with the (supposed known) value $\ln(2)\approx 0.69315$ and to evaluate the continued fraction up to $ [0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 3, 1]$ that is : $$\ln(2)\approx 0.69315\approx\cfrac 1{1+\cfrac 1{2+\cfrac 1{3+\cfrac 1{1+\cfrac 1{6+\cfrac 1{3+\cfrac 11}}}}}}=\frac {253}{365}$$

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Wow, I didn't realize that my bound is actually a convergent of $\log2$, although I suppose I could have guessed it given that it is accurate to $5$ digits with only $3$ digit inputs. I think your method is assuming the consequent, though, since if you know $\log 2$ to that many digits then you already have the answer.

Comment: Yes you are right (about the accuracy and... that I'm assuming the answer! :-)). This told you could use one of the generalized c.f. for $\ln(2)$ given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm_of_2#Other_representations) (except that I didn't get quickly the correct fraction...). Another c.f. is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula#The_natural_logarithm). Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\log 2=2\operatorname{arctanh}\frac{1}{3}$, we may use the series:
$$ \log 2 = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2}{(2n+1)\,3^{2n+1}} $$
and the bound:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 4}\frac{2}{(2n+1)\,3^{2n+1}}\leq\sum_{n\geq 4}\frac{2}{3^{2n+3}}=\frac{1}{157464} $$
to prove that (we just need the terms of the previous series till $n=4$):
$$ \log 2\approx \frac{4297606}{6200145} = \color{red}{0.69314}\color{blue}{60474\ldots}$$
where the red digits are the right ones for sure.

Comment: Yep, just about to add this one following  @columbus8myhw's suggestion to check Euler's "strongly convergent" $\log\frac{1+x}{1-x}=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$, which is essentially equivalent to using the arctan expansion. $4$ terms is very nice!

Answer (score 5):

You could express this as  $\log(1/2) > -\dfrac{253}{365}$.  The series 
$$\log(1/2) = \log(1-1/2) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n 2^n}$$ converges quickly, and has nice bounds:
$$ \log(1/2) \ge - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \dfrac{1}{n 2^n} - \sum_{n=N}^\infty \dfrac{1}{N 2^n} = - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \dfrac{1}{n 2^n} - \dfrac{1}{N 2^{N-1}}$$

EDIT:  Another way to write it is $2 < (\exp(1/365))^{253}$, and use the continued fraction 
$$ \exp(1/n) = 1 + \dfrac{1}{n-1 + \dfrac{1}{1 + \dfrac{1}{1 + \dfrac{1}{3n-1 + \dfrac{1}{1+ \dfrac{1}{1+ \dfrac{1}{5n-1 + \ldots}}}}}}}$$
In particular, $$\exp(1/365) >1+ 1/(364+1/(1+1/(1+1/1094))) = \dfrac{800080}{797891}$$
and (if you don't mind exact arithmetic with big integers)
$$\left(\dfrac{800080}{797891}\right)^{253} > 2$$

Comment: Oh, that's a good one, forgot about that symmetry of $\log$. For the record you need $12$ terms of that series to get the stated bound, at which point you are verifying $\frac{3935051}{5677056}<\frac{253}{365}$, which is quite respectable.

Answer (score 2):

We may use [this generalized continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm_of_2#Other_representations) to get directly excellent fractions as near as wished of $\,\ln\,2$ :
$$\ln\,2=\cfrac 1{1+\cfrac 1{2+\cfrac 1{3+\cfrac 2{2+\cfrac 2{5+\cfrac 3{2+\cfrac 3{7+\cfrac 4{2+\cfrac 4{9+\cdots}}}}}}}}}=b_0+\cfrac {a_1}{b_1+\cfrac {a_2}{b_2+\cfrac {a_3}{b_3+\cfrac {a_4}{\cdots}}}}$$

Let's obtain the first successive convergent using the previous values of $a_k,b_k$ and $\;\left[\matrix {n_k\\d_k}\right]=\left[\matrix {n_{k-1}\;n_{k-2}\\d_{k-1}\;d_{k-2}}\right]\left[\matrix {b_k\\a_k}\right],\quad\left[\matrix {n_1\\d_1}\right]=\left[\matrix {b_0\,b_1+a_1\\b_1}\right]=\left[\matrix {1\\1}\right],\;\left[\matrix {n_0\\d_0}\right]=\left[\matrix {b_0\\1}\right]=\left[\matrix {0\\1}\right]$ :

\begin{array} {l|c|ccccc}
k&b_k,a_k&&&f_k=\dfrac{n_k}{d_k}\\
\hline\\
1 & \color{#0000ff}{1,1} &\cfrac 1{1}&&=\cfrac 1{1}=\dfrac {n_1}{d_1}\\
2 & \color{#0000ff}{2,1} & \cfrac 1{1+\frac 1{2}}&=\dfrac{n_1 b_2+n_0 a_2}{d_1 b_2+d_0 a_2}=\dfrac{1\cdot\color{#0000ff}{2}+0\cdot\color{#0000ff}{1}}{1\cdot\color{#0000ff}{2}+1\cdot\color{#0000ff}{1}}&=\dfrac 23=\dfrac {n_2}{d_2}\\
3 & \color{#0000ff}{3,1} & \cfrac 1{1+\frac 1{2+\frac 1{3}}}&=\dfrac{n_2 b_3+n_1 a_3}{d_2 b_3+d_1 a_3}=\dfrac{2\cdot\color{#0000ff}{3}+1\cdot\color{#0000ff}{1}}{3\cdot\color{#0000ff}{3}+1\cdot\color{#0000ff}{1}}&=\dfrac {7}{10}=\dfrac {n_3}{d_3}\\
4 & \color{#0000ff}{2,2} &\cfrac 1{1+\frac 1{2+\frac 1{3+\frac 2{2}}}}&=\dfrac{7\cdot\color{#0000ff}{2}+2\cdot\color{#0000ff}{2}}{10\cdot\color{#0000ff}{2}+3\cdot\color{#0000ff}{2}}&=\dfrac {18}{26}=\dfrac {9}{13}\\
5 & \color{#0000ff}{5,2}&\cfrac 1{1+\frac 1{2+\frac 1{3+\frac 2{2+\frac 2{5}}}}}&=\dfrac{18\cdot\color{#0000ff}{5}+7\cdot\color{#0000ff}{2}}{26\cdot\color{#0000ff}{5}+10\cdot\color{#0000ff}{2}}&=\dfrac {104}{150}=\dfrac {52}{75}\\
6 & \color{#0000ff}{2,3}&\cfrac 1{1+\frac 1{2+\frac 1{3+\frac 2{2+\frac 2{5+\frac 3{2}}}}}}&=\dfrac{104\cdot\color{#0000ff}{2}+18\cdot\color{#0000ff}{3}}{150\cdot\color{#0000ff}{2}+26\cdot\color{#0000ff}{3}}&=\dfrac {262}{378}=\dfrac {131}{189}\\
7 & \color{#0000ff}{7,3}&\cfrac 1{1+\frac 1{2+\frac 1{3+\frac 2{2+\frac 2{5+\frac 3{2+\frac 3{7}}}}}}}&=\dfrac{262\cdot\color{#0000ff}{7}+104\cdot\color{#0000ff}{3}}{378\cdot\color{#0000ff}{7}+150\cdot\color{#0000ff}{3}}&=\dfrac {2146}{3096}=\dfrac {1073}{1548}\\
8 & \color{#0000ff}{2,4}&\cfrac 1{1+\frac 1{2+\frac 1{3+\frac 2{2+\frac 2{5+\frac 3{2+\frac 3{7+\frac 4{2}}}}}}}}&=\dfrac{2146\cdot\color{#0000ff}{2}+262\cdot\color{#0000ff}{4}}{3096\cdot\color{#0000ff}{2}+378\cdot\color{#0000ff}{4}}&=\dfrac {5340}{7704}=\dfrac {445}{642}\\
9 & \color{#0000ff}{9,4}&\cfrac 1{1+\frac 1{2+\frac 1{3+\frac 2{2+\frac 2{5+\frac 3{2+\frac 3{7+\frac 4{2+\frac 4{9}}}}}}}}}&=\dfrac{5340\cdot\color{#0000ff}{9}+2146\cdot\color{#0000ff}{4}}{7704\cdot\color{#0000ff}{9}+3096\cdot\color{#0000ff}{4}}&=\dfrac {56644}{81720}=\dfrac {14161}{20430}\\
\cdots &\\
\end{array}

For even values of $k$ the fraction will be too small while for odd values it will be too large. The last fraction provided here (for $k$ odd) is larger than $\,\ln\,2\,$ but smaller than your fraction proving your claim. The previous approximation is smaller than $\,\ln\,2\,$ (but more precise too than your fraction).

As observed earlier a convergent from the continued fraction of the numerical approximation $\,0.69315\;$ returns directly the initial fraction : $$\ln(2)\approx 0.69315\approx\cfrac 1{1+\cfrac 1{2+\cfrac 1{3+\cfrac 1{1+\cfrac 1{6+\cfrac 1{3+\cfrac 11}}}}}}=\frac {253}{365}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\log 2 = \log (1 + 1/3) + \log (1 + 1/2)$, and each of those terms can be easily evaluated to the desired predictions using $\log (1+x) = x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 - \cdots$.   There are other ways to write $\log 2$ as a sum of logarithms that will let you write it as a sum of more, but faster-converging series; I'm not sure what minimizes the arithmetic.  In general we have

$$ \log 2 = \log \left( 1 + {1 \over 2n-1} \right) + \log \left( 1 + {1 \over 2n-2} \right) + \cdots + \log \left(1 + {1 \over n} \right)$$

of which the original identity I gave is the $n = 2$ case.