# How to derive this continued fraction formula of $\ln(2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, continued-fractions

On wiki page [Naturel logarithhm of 2, other representations section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm_of_2#Other_representations) it lists
$$\ln\,2=\cfrac 1{1+\cfrac 1{2+\cfrac 1{3+\cfrac 2{2+\cfrac 2{5+\cfrac 3{2+\cfrac 3{7+\cfrac 4{2+\cfrac 4{9+\cdots}}}}}}}}}$$

How to derive this? I checked [Euler's continued fraction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula) page but still couldn't figure out how the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are derived.

[A math stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1238285/26632) mentioned
$$\;\left[\matrix {n_k\\d_k}\right]=\left[\matrix {n_{k-1}\;n_{k-2}\\d_{k-1}\;d_{k-2}}\right]\left[\matrix {b_k\\a_k}\right],\quad\left[\matrix {n_1\\d_1}\right]=\left[\matrix {b_0\,b_1+a_1\\b_1}\right]=\left[\matrix {1\\1}\right],\;\left[\matrix {n_0\\d_0}\right]=\left[\matrix {b_0\\1}\right]=\left[\matrix {0\\1}\right]$$
but didn't explain where this is from.

Comment: Perhaps there is a link with the alternating series for $\log 2$, but not sure.

Comment: The Wikipedia formula has a reference attached to it -- did you check that?

Comment: @Thomas ah i see it, thanks!

Comment: Khovanskii addresses this in [The Application of continued fractions and their generalization to problems in approximation theory](https://books.google.cz/books/about/The_application_of_continued_fractions_a.html?id=7w_vAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y),  section 4 - Continued Fraction Expansions of the Natural Logarithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given continued fraction, rewritten as $$L=\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1^2}{2+\cfrac{1^2}{3+\cfrac{2^2}{4+\cfrac{2^2}{5+\cfrac{3^2}{6+\cfrac{3^2}{7+\ddots}}}}}}},$$ is a special case of [Gauss's continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_continued_fraction#The_series_2F1) for $_2F_1$ (taken at $a=0$, $b=c=1$, $z=-1$): $$\frac{_2F_1(a+1,b;c+1;z)}{_2F_1(a,b;c;z)}=\cfrac{c}{c+\cfrac{(a-c)bz}{c+1+\cfrac{(b-c-1)(a+1)z}{c+2+\cfrac{(a-c-1)(b+1)z}{c+3+\cfrac{(b-c-2)(a+2)z}{c+4+\ddots}}}}}.$$

Now $_2F_1(0,1;1;z)=1$ and $_2F_1(1,1;2;z)=-\ln(1-z)/z$ give the expected $L=\ln 2$.