# Solving a functional equation for finding equivalent resistance in an infinite ladder

Tags: physics, functional-equations

I was trying out a physics question to find the equivalent resistance between two points A and B.

[image]

I got a functional equation on solving, but I couldn't proceed further. Finding f(1) gives the answer to the question.

\begin{gather*}
\frac{( x+1) f( x+2)}{( x+1) +f( x+2)} \ +\ x=f( x) \ \\
\end{gather*}

Is it possible to solve it, or should I consider a different approach?

Comment: While the elements along each branch are different, you may find the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3468013/solve-functional-equation-hyh-1y-2yy2?rq=1) of interest.

Comment: Also, this functional equation agrees (for positive odd integer $k$) with the recursion obtained by JJacquelin below under the identification $x=2k+1$, $f(x)=R_k$. (I think one must also demand that $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ to get a unique solution: otherwise one could pick $f(1)$ arbitrarily and generate $f(x)$ accordingly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First consider a finit ladder (limited to $n$ rungs) drawing below.

If n is sufficiently large the equivalent resistance $R_0$ is quite undependent from the last resistor i.e. what ever $R_n$ be from $0$ to infinity. This is easy to check with numerical recursive calculus thanks to the formula below.

For an infinite ladder the limit found is :
$$\boxed{R_0\simeq 2.485339738238447...}$$

[image]

Of course the value found is not analytic but numerical. So my answer isn't a final answer.

Hint : Thanks to ISC (Inverse Symbolic Calculator) one can guess a probable analytic formula :
$$R_0=\frac{4}{\ln(5)}\simeq 2.48533973823844724...$$
The councidence is correct for more than 16 digits. The proposed formula can be considered as a good conjecture.

The above result was obtained with my own ISC : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14161596/Mathematiques-experimentales

Similar studies about ladders made of not only resistors but mixed resistors and capacitors : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/71923015/The-Phasance-Concept

Comment: The recursion formula for resistance suggests some kind of continued fraction. This has been explored previously (see for instance the paper [here](https://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-2020/ams-13-16-2020/p/peranoAMS13-16-2020.pdf)) but it’s not evident to me that a closed form is known.

Comment: Also, Mathematica supports your conjecture (up to several hundred digits in precision). The form of it does make me wonder if it's better to look at the conductance $G_0:=1/R_0\underset{?}{=} \ln(5)/4.$ In particular, the continued-fraction representation for $\ln(1+z)$ found [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/10/0001/) seems propitious.

Comment: Is it possible to solve the functional equation without a calculator

Comment: Also: the above continued fraction is a special case of Gauss's continued fraction, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3750930/137524). This might mean that there's a way to express $R_k$ explicitly as a hypergeometric function, just as $\ln(5)/4={_2}F_1(1,1;2;-4)$ is.